# Android to C++ Socket connection closes after file was received

Tags: android, c++, sockets, message, file-transfer

I have the following problem:
I have an Android application, which sends a Picture to a C++ Server, which computes some parameters and sends them back to the client. But when the file is sent and everything is computed the phone is not able to receive the message, and my LogCat says "Socket Closed".

But if I comment out the code which sends and receives the Image, the Client is able to receive a Message from the server. Why is this not possible then after the Image was sent?

Here is my relevant code:

Android:

```
String picturePath = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_0004.jpg";
            final File picture = new File(picturePath);
                        if (picture.exists()) {
                            try {
                                //reading file and sending to server
                                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(picture);
                                Log.d(TAG, "trying to connect");
                                String st = "laber";
                                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.12", port);

                                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
                                tv.setText(st);
                                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (s.getInputStream());
                                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                int read = 0;
                                int totBytes = 0;
                                while ((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1)
                                {
                                    totBytes = totBytes + read;
                                    out.write(buf, 0, read);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Image - Read: " + read + " - Total " + totBytes + " bytes!");

                                }
                                out.flush();

                                out.close();
                                st = in.readLine();
                                fis.close();


                                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting" + " "+ st+ " " +st.compareTo("laber"));



                                tv.setText(st);


                                // Close connection
                                s.close();
                                Log.d(TAG, "connection closed " + st);
                                dataReceived=true;
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

C++

```
SOCKET TempSock=SOCKET_ERROR;
while(TempSock==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout<<"Waiting for incoming connections...\r\n";
    TempSock=accept(Socket,NULL,NULL);
}
Socket=TempSock;
int totalBytes = 0;
ofstream outFile;
char buf[1024] = "";
int received = 0;
if (outFile != NULL) 
{
    outFile.open("C:\\test\\ReceivedFiles\\test.jpg" , ofstream::binary);
    cout << "File opened!" << endl;
} else 
{
    cout << "Can't open file!" << endl;
}
//receiving file and writing to disk
while ((received = recv(Socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) > 0) 
{
    cout << "R:" << received << " ";
    if (received > 0) 
    {
        totalBytes += received;
        if (outFile.is_open()) 
        {
            outFile.write(buf, received); 
            cout << " (Total: " << totalBytes << " B)" << endl;
        } else
        cout << "Error in recv() function, received bytes = " << received << endl;
    } else 
        cout << "R:" << received << " ";
}

std::cout<<"Client connected!\r\n\r\n";

initImageSearch();
readFiles();
keypointMatching();
searchBundleOut();
ransacMatrices();
getRotationOrientation();

//send message back to client
string message = doubleToString(viewingDirectionArray[0])+" "+doubleToString(viewingDirectionArray[1])+" "+doubleToString(viewingDirectionArray[2])+" "+doubleToString(positionArray[0])+" "+doubleToString(positionArray[1])+" "+doubleToString(positionArray[2])+" 0.5 0.5 0.5 baum";
const char *szMessage;
szMessage = "123 456 789 246 135 178 189";//message.c_str();


int msg = send(Socket,szMessage,strlen(szMessage),0);
std::cout<<msg<<endl;
// Shutdown socket
shutdown(Socket,SD_SEND);

// Close socket entirely
closesocket(Socket);

// Cleanup Winsock
WSACleanup();
```

Comment: Try moving `out.close()` to after you're done reading. (Can't remember if that's a possible problem or not.)

Comment: I also tried to do this, but then my c++ Server doesn't know when the file was received completely and doesn't go on with the other functions.
Anyway, this is just the OutputSteam, the Socket should still be open I think. Or am I wrong?

Comment: where is your socket initialization for c++?

Comment: Regarding the problem with not knowing when you received all of some stream yet, you should probably change the "protocol" to add either a special terminator marker that not going to be in the stream, or before the stream add the total length.

Comment: So, do I unterstand this right? The problem is really with closing the outputsteam and I have to determine the end of file with another method?

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, you are right, I found a solution. I deleted the out.close() line and checked in C++ for the end of the file and then terminated the while-loop

Answer (score 0):

Close the output stream when you are finished with the connection, and not before. Closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the socket and the other stream. Closing any stream or reader or writer wrapped around another stream closes that stream.